# How to programmatically create a GitHub repository?

Tags: java, github

I have to use Java to programmatically create a GitHub repository and push code to it. Please advise on the best method to use. Also please share any code snippet or related links for the utility.

I referred jgit library, has anyone used it? I also referred hub, gh and command line utility.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the GitHub Rest API.

Generate a Personal Access Token from `Settings > Developers Settings > Personal Access Tokens`

Once generated use that to call the endpoint -

```
https://api.github.com/user/repo
```

with body

```
{"name": "REPO_NAME"}
```

and Header

```
Authorization: token PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Example Curl:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token PERSONAL_ACCESS TOKEN" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name": "REPO_NAME"}'
```

Reference Doc: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user

Answer (score 0):

The gitlab4j api is a great library to do so : https://github.com/gitlab4j/gitlab4j-api

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gitlab4j/gitlab4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gitlab4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>gitlab4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm using to read files from repo, commit and create merge requests :

```
try {
        var branchName = "BRANCH-" + random.nextLong();
        var action = new CommitAction();
        action.withContent(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(data))
                .withFilePath(JSON_FILE_PATH).setAction(Action.UPDATE);
        try (var glapi = new GitLabApi(GIT_HOSTNAME, token)) {
            glapi.enableRequestResponseLogging(java.util.logging.Level.INFO);
            glapi.getCommitsApi().createCommit(REPO_NAME, branchName, message, VERSION, null, null, action);
            return glapi.getMergeRequestApi().createMergeRequest(DB_REPO_NAME, branchName, VERSION, message,
                    message, ADMIN_USER_ID);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new DataException(ex);
    }
```

how to create a new repo, a new master branch and your first commit :

```
try (var glapi = new GitLabApi("https://gitlab.com/", token)) {
            var projectApi = glapi.getProjectApi();
            var project = projectApi.createProject("my-repo");
            // my-repo created
            var action = new CommitAction();
            action.withContent("### ignore some files ###").withFilePath(".gitignore").setAction(Action.CREATE);
            glapi.getCommitsApi().createCommit("my-repo", "master", "my first commit", "master", "author@mail.com",
                    "author", action);
            // yoru first commit 
        }
```

**for github you can use https://github.com/hub4j/github-api**

```
@Test
public void testCreateRepoPublic() throws Exception {
    initGithubInstance();
    GHUser myself = gitHub.getMyself();
    String repoName = "test-repo-public";
    GHRepository repo = gitHub.createRepository(repoName).private_(false).create();
    try {
        assertThat(repo.isPrivate(), is(false));
        repo.setPrivate(true);
        assertThat(myself.getRepository(repoName).isPrivate(), is(true));
        repo.setPrivate(false);
        assertThat(myself.getRepository(repoName).isPrivate(), is(false));
    } finally {
        repo.delete();
    }
}
```

commiting multiple files :

```
    var repo = github.getRepository("my-repo");
    GHRef mainRef = repo.getRef("heads/master");
    String mainTreeSha = repo.getTreeRecursive("master", 1).getSha();
    GHTreeBuilder treeBuilder = repo.createTree().baseTree(mainTreeSha);
    treeBuilder.add("file1.txt", Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("file1.txt"), false);
    treeBuilder.add("file2.json", Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("file2.json"), false);
    treeBuilder.add("dir1/dir2/file3.xml", Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("dir1/dir2/file3.xml"), false);
  
    String treeSha = treeBuilder.create().getSha();
    GHCommit commit = repo.createCommit()
            .tree(treeSha)
            .message("adding multiple files example")
            .author("author", "author@mail.com", new Date())
            .committer("committer", "committer@mail.com", new Date())
            .parent(mainRef.getObject().getSha())
            .create();
    String commitSha = commit.getSHA1();
    mainRef.updateTo(commitSha);
```

**Using eclipse jgit**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.202206071550-r</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Examples :**

```
    // to use basic auth
    var credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("user", "password");

    // to clone a repository
    Git.cloneRepository().setURI("https://github.com/my-repo.git").setCredentialsProvider(credentials).call();

    // to init a new repository
    Git.init().setDirectory(new File("/opt/my-repo")).setInitialBranch("master").call();

    // to use a cloned repo
    var git = Git.open(new File("/opt/my-repo"));

    // to pull changes from remote
    git.pull().setCredentialsProvider(credentials).call();

    // to stage one file
    git.add().setUpdate(true).addFilepattern("dir/file.txt").call();

    // to stage all files in a directory
    git.add().setUpdate(true).addFilepattern("dir").call();

    // to create a commit with the staged files
    git.commit().setMessage("just adding some files.").call();

    // to push changes to remote
    git.push().call();
```

Comment: Could you please share for repo creation also? And does this work for github?

Comment: Hello, I just updated my answer. hope it helps

Comment: gitlabapi works for github?

Comment: @vkl for github you can use https://github.com/hub4j/github-api. I updated my answer again.

Comment: please share snippet for commit also using github-api to push some set of files and folders to the repo into a particular branch

Comment: You can check the test package for the repo, it contains all the examples : https://github.com/hub4j/github-api/blob/main/src/test/java/org/kohsuke/github/GHContentIntegrationTest.java
something like this : 
 repo.createContent("this is an awesome file I created",
                "creating a new text file.",
                "newFile.txt");

Comment: Is there a way to push all files and folders together in a single commit. We can't do it one by one isn't it

Comment: You can use Tree builder for this. I updated the answer with a code snippet

Comment: Thanks Habib. I want to just commit everything(all files and dirs) in the local repo folder - can we achieve this using the api, without having to mention the files in a tree builder?

Comment: If you want to clone the repo, modify locally , commit and push changes (like an ide git extension) you can use eclipse git plugin.

Comment: I want to create a repo. So I can create it using the api,  then use the git plugin to clone using the standard url format and commit changes?

Comment: If you want files to be present physically then you can use the plugin for all these things ( init the repo, set the remote, commit files and push branches easily). I don't have code snippets, but I remember that you need to create Command objects and execute them (InitCommand, CommitCommand.. etc)

Comment: Thanks Habib. If possible,  please share any git plugin related links for code snippets.

Comment: You are welcome. I just updated my answer with code snippets using eclipse jgit. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Habib.. I will refer to it. Along with jgit, before cloning, we have to create the repo using github api right?   And for using jgit, could you please share the import statement for the library to use directly in Java code

Comment: Correct ! I already mentioned the maven dependency that you can use for jgit. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit

Comment: Without using maven, can we just import the jgit library in the Java code? Is it the same url that you have given - can it be used in the import statement in the Java code?

Comment: You can download the jar from maven repo and add it to the build path of your java project.

Comment: is it possible to create the repository under the organization,  how to mention it?

Comment: GHRepository r = gitHub.getOrganization("org-name").createRepository("repo-name")
                .description("a test repository under org")
                .private_(false)
                .create();

Comment: Somehow I couldn't use the github api. Initgithubinstance method is not recognized.  Also I tried the create repository method - it's deprecated.

Comment: So, I went onto use gh cli. The problem with cli is I can't add contributors or check if the repo exists. I have to use curl for these and somehow I can't get the working curl commands to go through in java, it's not working.  I asked a question on this today

Comment: i tried the jgit to add files to the github repo. Commit is getting created, but the files are not added, below is my code snippet:

Comment: I added the code in the other question.  Please check

Comment: If we are adding new files, setupdate should be false or should not be set?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the jgit to add files to the GitHub repo. Commit is getting created, but the files are not added, In addfilepattern - I tried "." as well. Below is my code snippet:

```js
Git.cloneRepository().setURI("https://github.com/"+org+"/"+repo+".git").setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).setDirectory(new File(Gitpath)).setCloneAllBranches(true).call();

Git.init().setDirectory(new File(Gitpath)).setInitialBranch("main").call();

var git = Git.open(new File(Gitpath));
git.add().setUpdate(true).addFilepattern(directoryName+fileName).call();
git.commit().setMessage("Adding files.").call();
git.push().setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).call();
```